# Equirectangular map on Web

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, formula, mercator

I plan to build an online map for markers (pins) of a game and I don't manage to set the correct latitude of my markers.

Original map is a **square of 2048*2048px**

Then I got markers (many thousands)

Map coordinates are set with a x, y notation from 0 to 100.
0, 0 is the **top left** corner and 100, 100 is the **bottom right** corner of the map.
x=50, y=50 is lat = 0°, lng = 0° (the center of the picture).

To convert from my notation to longitude I use this JS function, it works well :

```
        function longitude(x)
        {
            var lng = 0
            if (x < 50) // Negative Longitude (West)
            {
                lng = (x - 50) / 50 * 180;
            }
            else // Positive Longitude (East)
            {
                lng = (50 - x) / 50 * 180;
            }
            return lng
        }
```

But for latitude it don't work because those engines use a Mercator projection and me not.

If someone have the correct formula, it would be greatly appreciated :(

Comment: Hi Ayantir, and welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say "those engines use a Mercator projection", what do you mean? These *engines* aren't mentioned in the rest of your question.

Comment: Did you take a look at this Google example already? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

Comment: Thank you, and sorry, I used first Google Maps JS API V3 and then moved to leaflet. I saw this page yes, but didn't find anything (does it exists?) to change the projection on GMaps. (that's why I moved to Leaflet which seemed more flexible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

If you are using Leaflet, you should specify the map option [`crs`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-crs) and use [`L.CRS.Simple`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#defined-crs-l.crs.simple):

> A simple CRS that maps longitude and latitude into `x` and `y` directly. May be used for maps of flat surfaces (e.g. game maps). Note that the `y` axis should still be inverted (going from bottom to top).

This will avoid the [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) projection, especially the latitude which is a special computation as you figured out (see the linked Wikipedia article for the equation).

Then you are left with correctly mapping your `x` and `y` coordinates to your need, especially in respect with your map image.

For instance, assuming you set your map image as:

```js
L.imageOverlay("imageUrl", [[0, 0], [256, 256]]).addTo(map);
```

(so that it fits the equivalent of 1 tile at zoom level 0)

Then you could have a conversion like:

```js
function longitude(x) {
  return x / 100 * 256;
}

function latitude(y) {
  return 256 - y / 100 * 256; // Still need to revert y.
}
```

Comment: Okay, My map was not really set as you quoted, but it works !

Comment: I tiled my map, so I'm doing this :


  var southWest = L.latLng(-256, 0),
  northEast = L.latLng(0, 256),
  bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);


  var tamrielMap = L.map('map', {
   center: [-128, 128],
   maxBounds: bounds,
   zoom: 3,
   minZoom: 3,
   maxZoom: 3,
   crs: L.CRS.Simple
  });


  L.tileLayer('../source/png_SOH/alikr/alikr_base_{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(tamrielMap);


  function longitude(x) {
   return x / 100 * 256; // Tiles size
  }


  function latitude(y) {
   return (0 - y / 100 * 256);
  }

(sorry for markdown editing)