# Leaftet coordinates plotting axis issue

Tags: jquery, leaflet

Im trying to plot markers on an image using leaflet library the issue im facing is as follows:

Leaflet plots x,y coordinates from lower left ,whereas the coordinates i receive from the service plots the coordinates assuming axis is top left.

```
var pixelsPerUnit = site.siteImageHeightinPX  / site.height;

    for (var i = 0; i < ap.length; i++) {
                 var x = ap[i].xPos * pixelsPerUnit;
                 var y = ap[i].yPos * pixelsPerUnit; 
                    console.log(x+"   "+y);
                    var m = L.marker(xy(x,y), {icon: apIcon});
                    markers.addLayer(m);
                }
```

json

```
{
  "site": {
    "width": 308.44,
    "height": 205.63,
    "siteImageWidthinPX": 3456,
    "siteImageHeightinPX": 2304,
    "testPoints": [
      {
        "testPointID": "1712",
        "xPos": 44.366,
        "yPos": 52.114
      },
      {
        "testPointID": "1701",
        "xPos": 94.87,
        "yPos": 54.276
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[CLICK TO VIEW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neswa.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484700/leaflet-latlngbounds-with-simpler-crs-projection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001349/equirectangular-map-on-web/39002906#39002906