# Force leaflet to use custom coordinate system

Tags: javascript, leaflet, coordinates

this is the corner of my map
[image: My map]

Red shown is my target coordinate system, I have a program that generates markers for that coordinate system, just positive X and Y from that 0,0 point

however currently that corner 0,0 is in leaflet's latlng represented as 0,-180. ane that brown dot on the bottom of the island is about -14,-166, when in reality it is at around 310,320

I have searched for quite a while, I found some ways of translating the coordinates, but always between known and commonly used systems, not "made up" custom ones.

Anyone have an idea?

EDIT:
*CRS.SIMPLE* does solve this problem if you use L.ImageOverlay or tiles that are not TMS

Which in my case is doable, not ideal, but doable. Question then remains, how to achieve this with TMS tiles.

Comment: There's an entire tutorial on how to use `L.CRS.Simple` at http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001349/equirectangular-map-on-web

Comment: Does that work with tiles? Seems to mess them up for me

Comment: Looks like setting CRS to CRS.Simple overrides the tms:true in the tilelayer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equirectangular map on Web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001349/equirectangular-map-on-web)

Comment: As I said, setting CRS to single overrides TMS:True set for the layer of tiles.. Because I use tiles, not a image overlay .. Tiles generated by gdal2tiles, which generates tiles for the TMS:True setting

Comment: @Poody your TMS issue sounds like it should be a separate question.